# The torso and skirt texture is distorted yet everything else is fine

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I have been trying to fix this for a while now and I have NO clue on what else to do. Could someone explain what happened and what I did wrong?

Face Texture? Perfect! Leg Texture? Perfect but for some reason, the torso and skirt isn't okay? I don't understand what is going on with the model to make it mess up like that.

I just find it upsetting how it's so close to perfection but the textures are in the way

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @icYou520 okay so, the torso's texture is distorted, it is not supposed to look like that. https://imgur.com/a/CoPSmuu it should look like this. You see, most of the textures are okie dokie, it just not those two parts. I already fixed the hair but I can't fix the body textures

Comment: @icYou520 that's understandable, I got a bit too desperate and couldn't think rip. Will edit the post!

Comment: after looking at your edit, I am almost positive that its because the uv layout is off on the torso and skirt. I would leave the windows open how you have it on the last picture and grab the faces (or vertices in the UV editor window) and move them around and you should see it update on the model itself. I think you just need to clean up the unwrap a little bit. Maybe one of the more knowledgeable people here can help a little bit more. This is just my best guess.

Comment: @icYou520 Thank you for trying to help! I was thinking about that but I wasn't 100% sure. I will try to move it around a bit.

Comment: Im not sure if you need more points to upload a blend file but if you want to try I can take a look at it http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @icYou520 Yes, please! I tried your method but things didn't get any better. I put the file on the post.

Comment: It looks like the textures didnt get packed into the blend file. Go to File>External Data and check "Automatically pack into blend" save it again delete this one and upload the new one.

Comment: @icYou520 done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed your blend file for you.

This is a terrible answer and maybe the mods will erase this, Basically the uv's were off and it was too much trouble to manually try to fix them all. So I just erased half of your mesh and then added a mirror modifier so the texture exactly matches on both sides.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, dude! It looks so much better now :) I need to give you something one day. You really helped me out here.

Comment: Just click the green check mark and we are all good! glad I could help

Comment: the pain is finally over and now I can start planning on how to rig the model! thank you once again.